# Thread having effect on another thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

So I want to make a task list with a built-in timer per task for training purposes. The idea is that I can start a top-level task and after the timer of this task has finished, a subtask will be started given that a subtask was attached to the top-level task. I use Java Swing to provide a GUI which can start a task. Each task should create an own instance of my `Timer` class for measuring the duration of the task. The `TaskObject` class starts a Timer via `startTask()`.

The problem:

When I attach a subtask, the subtask is started, but the its timer wont stop after it has finished. It reaches the end of the while-loop but somehow it enters and leaves the loop continuously and I have no idea, why that is. A top-level task alone runs perfectly fine. The timer stops after the given duration. Maybe you could help me out here?

Thanks in advance! Here is the short version of my code:

```
public class Timer {

    private Thread watchThread;
    private long deltaTime;
    private volatile boolean run;
    private long time1, time2;

    ITaskObject task;

    public Timer(ITaskObject task){
        super();
        this.deltaTime = 0;
        this.run = false;
        this.task = task;
    }

    public void start(){
        createThread();
        run = true;
        watchThread.start();
    }

    public void stop(){
        watchThread.interrupt();    
        run = false;
    }

    public void reset(){
        run = false;
        time1 = 0;
        deltaTime = 0;
    }

    private void createThread(){
        watchThread = new Thread(() -> {
            time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while(run){
                time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                deltaTime = time2 - time1;
                task.addTime((double)deltaTime);
                time1 = time2;
            }

        });
    }
}
```

```
/* imports */

public class TaskObject extends JPanel implements ITaskObject{

    private String taskName = "default";
    private double millisMax = 0;
    private double currentMillis;
    private Timer timer;
    private State state;
    private FontMetrics metrics;
    private Font myFont;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private TaskObject nextSubtask;

    public TaskObject(String taskName, int millisMax){
        super();
        setSize(500, 70);
        this.currentMillis = 0;
        this.nextSubtask = null;
        this.state = State.UNDEF;
        this.taskName = taskName;
        this.millisMax = millisMax;
        this.myFont = new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 20);   
    }

    @Override
    public void startTask(){
        state = State.RUNNING;
        timer = new Timer(this);
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void addTime(double millis){
        currentMillis += millis;
        if(currentMillis >= millisMax){
            stopTask();
            currentMillis = millisMax;
            startSubtask();
        }
        this.repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void stopTask(){
        state = State.STOPPED;
        timer.stop();
        timer.reset();
        repaint();
    }

    @Override 
    public void resetTask(){
        currentMillis = 0;
        stopTask();
        state = State.UNDEF;
    }

    @Override
    public void resumeTask() {
        timer.start();
        state = State.RUNNING;
    }

    @Override
    public void startSubtask() {
        if(nextSubtask != null){
            nextSubtask.startTask();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void attachSubtask(TaskObject task) {
        nextSubtask = task;
    }
}
```

```
/* imports */

public class GUI extends JFrame{

    private int wX, wY;
    private TaskObject task;
    private PopUpMenu contextMenu;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GUI(1200, 700);
    }

    public GUI(int wX, int wY){

        /*
         *
         */

        task = new TaskObject("Light Training", 3000);
        /* some settings for the panel itself */
        add(task);
        task.repaint();
        task.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
                if(me.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1){
                    switch(task.getState()){
                        case UNDEF:
                            int answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(GUI.this, "Do you want to start this task?", "Confirmation", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
                            if(answer == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
                                task.startTask();
                            }
                        case STOPPED: 
                            task.resumeTask();
                            System.out.println("Resumed task");
                        case RUNNING:
                        default:
                    }

                }
            }
        });

        TaskObject task2 = new TaskObject("Subtask 1", 2000);
        /* settings for the panel */
        add(task2);
        task2.repaint();
        task2.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            /* same as above, theoretically runnable from here */
        });

        /* the next task to be started if the top-level task has finished */
        task.attachSubtask(task2);

        /* */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `addTime` method will always call the `startSubtask` method if it finds that the current task is out of time. That means that it is constantly telling the subtask to start, even after the subtask has already finished.

What I would suggest doing, is checking the state of the subtask in the `addTime` method: if the `subTask` is `STOPPED`, then do not start it again, as it has already run:

```
@Override
public void addTime(double millis) {
    currentMillis += millis;
    if (currentMillis >= millisMax) {
        stopTask();
        currentMillis = millisMax;
        // Only start the subtask if it is new or has been reset
        if (subtask.state == State.UNDEF) {
            startSubtask();
        }
    }
    this.repaint();
}
```

Another option is to only execute the `addTime` method if the task is currently in the `RUNNING` state:

```
@Override
public void addTime(double millis) {
    if (state == State.RUNNING) {
        currentMillis += millis;
        if (currentMillis >= millisMax) {
            stopTask();
            currentMillis = millisMax;
            startSubtask();
        }
    }
    this.repaint();
}
```